# Unable to find the contacts backed up to Google account after the loss of the phone

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, contacts

I backed up my contacts to my Google account. I recently got my phone stolen. I have the same number. I have found some pictures from my previous phone but I **can't find my contacts**! Some of these cannot be replaced. The only thing I can find is how to restore contacts from my current phone. How to get my friends back?

Comment: Was sync enabled on your old phone? If not than there is a huge chance that the backup has never been created.

Comment: You **got** your phone stolen? You want to get your **friends** back? Firstly, this is all extremely fishy (:()) and secondly, this is also horribly unclear. Please clarify your question to be in simple terms with as little extraneous detail as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Google offers an option to restore your contacts to any state within the past 30 days. This may help you recover deleted contacts. Just go to https://contacts.google.com/, click on More -> Restore contacts.

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you log in with your Google account into your phone it should automatically sync those contacts into your device if sync is on.